# EntityFramework throws AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: entity-framework

The setup:
EntityFramework POCO with proxies (+LazyLoading)

`Component` and `Part` classes both implement `IDataErrorInfo` (if this is necessary). The following code throws exception:

```
// Context is a singleton here
Context.LoadProperty<Part>(
    partEntity, 
    (e) => e.ChildComponents, 
    MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

The ambiguous property is `ChildComponents` as I can tell yet there is no other property with the same name, its only definition is:

```
public virtual ICollection<Component> ChildComponents { get; set; }
```

This is overridden in EF proxy and changed into something like

```
public virtual EntityCollection<Component> ChildComponents { get; set; }
```

Yet this issue just appeared and I cannot understand why now as there were no real changes.

Comment: In my case, one of my entities had a scalar property with the same name as an association property, with only a different casing. This caused the `AmbiguousMatchException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated this matter and turns out that .NET compiles indexers (e.g. from IDataErrorInfo) into `Item`, therefore introducing some kind of ambiguousness in a class that is called Item and any classes that have such a property. That causes problems in EF. This problem is buried in my code more deeply than I thought and not all info is present in initial post (mainly the fact that `Component` class has an `Item` property).